# Make the Remove repository button more visible on the Careers site

Tags: feature-request, jobs, github

I can see buttons to Add and Update my repos with my profile... but no where to remove them.

I think users should be given the ability to remove repositories from their public profile after they have added them.

---

## Update

It appears the button does exist, just not in a sensible area (imo). 
So, I will change my request to make this button more visible (I like Tims idea below).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the main edit view of your profile, click the edit link underneath the project you want to remove:

[image: edit link]

Then in the right-hand corner, click the remove link to remove the project from your profile:

[image: remove link]

It'd probably be nice if this option was available on the GitHub repositories page as well, as an additional button on the right-hand side, or as a link next to where it tells you that the project is already listed on your profile:

[image: remove link mock-up]

Comment: Good stuff... I am 100% in agreement this needs to be more visible to the user.